# Managing JOINs on an unknown number of EAV attributes

Tags: php, mysql

Given a table named `item` that has "master" records in it, such as:

```
item_id    item_type    item_name    item_description
1          clothing     T-Shirt      Get your t-shirt here
2          clothing     Polo Shirt   Another kind of short-sleeve shirt
3          computer     Macbook      2016 Macbook Pro with retina
```

And another table called `custom_fields` that has what I believe would be called an EAV structure (Entity-Attribute-Value):

```
id       item_id     attribute    value
1        1           size         large
2        1           color         purple
3        2           size          medium
4        2           color         green
5        3           memory        16GB
6        3           hard drive    512GB SSD
```

What is the best way to code a query that would include all of the specified / configured attributes **that also would support** an `ORDER BY`?

Facts:
1. The data structure cannot change.
2. The attributes are unknown (user-configured).
3. There are technically unlimited number of "attributes" (such as `size` or `color` above) that might be set up for a given type of item (practically, I can't imagine more than 50).
4. Which attributes are / are not included in a query is unknown (user-configured).

Assuming the attributes specified exist in an array, such as:

```
$attributes = ['size', 'color'];
```

It seems that some PHP that does something like:

```
$counter = 1;
$from = 'item AS i';
$fields = 'name, description';
$order_by = 'size';

foreach( $attributes AS $attribute ) {
    $table_alias = "a{$counter}";
    $fields.= ",{$table_alias}.value AS {$attribute}";
    $from.= " INNER JOIN custom_fields AS {$table_alias} ON i.item_id = {$table_alias}.item_id AND {$table_alias}.attribute = '{$attribute}'";
    $counter++;
}   

$query = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$from} {$where} ORDER BY {$order_by}";
```

Would construct a query that would be usable for both including the data, as well as permitting an ORDER BY.  That query would look something like:

```
SELECT name, description, a1.value AS size, a2.value AS color 
    FROM item AS i 
    INNER JOIN custom_fields AS a1 ON i.item_id = a1.item_id 
        AND a1.attribute = 'size'
    INNER JOIN custom_fields AS a2 ON i.item_id = a2.item_id 
        AND a2.attribute = 'color'
```

However, if there are 20+ columns, my concern is that this query seems obnoxious (20 `JOINS`) and might have performance issues.

Is there a better way to structure this? Is there some method, such as using temporary tables, that could be more useful or performant?

**Update:**
The version of MySQL cannot be ensured to be anything specific, so this should be compatible with any version, so please assume **version 5.0**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with only one **JOIN* like this:

```
SELECT m.*
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'color', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'color'
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'size', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'size'
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'memory', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'memory'
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'hard drive', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'hard drive'
FROM master m
LEFT JOIN custom_fields cf ON m.item_id = cf.item_id
GROUP BY m.item_id;
```

To generate a query for a product (or more) you can use this:
For all Products remove line **WHERE item_id in (1);**

SELECT m.*

```
select DISTINCT
 CONCAT("SELECT m.*\n"
 , GROUP_CONCAT(",GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = '",attribute,"', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS '",attribute,"'" SEPARATOR '\n')
 , "FROM master m\nLEFT JOIN custom_fields cf ON m.item_id = cf.item_id\nGROUP BY m.item_id") as myquery
FROM custom_fields
WHERE item_id in (1);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select DISTINCT
    ->  CONCAT("SELECT m.*\n"
    ->  , GROUP_CONCAT(",GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = '",attribute,"', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS '",attribute,"'" SEPARATOR '\n')
    ->  , "FROM master m\nLEFT JOIN custom_fields cf ON m.item_id = cf.item_id\nGROUP BY m.item_id") as myquery
    -> FROM custom_fields;
```

**Result**

```
    SELECT m.*
,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'size', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'size'
,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'color', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'color'
,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'size', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'size'
,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'color', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'color'
,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'memory', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'memory'
,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'hard drive', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'hard drive'FROM master m
LEFT JOIN custom_fields cf ON m.item_id = cf.item_id
GROUP BY m.item_id 

1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**and execute this query**

```
mysql>  SELECT m.*
    -> ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'size', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'size'
    -> ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'color', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'color'
    -> ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'size', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'size'
    -> ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'color', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'color'
    -> ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'memory', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'memory'
    -> ,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = 'hard drive', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS 'hard drive'FROM master m
    -> LEFT JOIN custom_fields cf ON m.item_id = cf.item_id
    -> GROUP BY m.item_id ;
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| item_id | item_type | item_name  | item_description                   | size   | color  | size   | color  | memory | hard drive |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|       1 | clothing  | T-Shirt    | Get your t-shirt here              | large  | purple | large  | purple | NULL   | NULL       |
|       2 | clothing  | Polo Shirt | Another kind of short-sleeve shirt | medium | green  | medium | green  | NULL   | NULL       |
|       3 | computer  | macbook    | 2016 Macbook Pro with retina       | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | 16GB   | 512GB SSD  |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**sample with PREPARED STATEMENT**

```
mysql> select DISTINCT
    ->  CONCAT("SELECT m.*\n"
    ->  , GROUP_CONCAT(",GROUP_CONCAT(IF(cf.attribute = '",attribute,"', cf.`value`, NULL)) AS '",attribute,"'" SEPARATOR '\n')
    ->  , "FROM master m\nLEFT JOIN custom_fields cf ON m.item_id = cf.item_id\nGROUP BY m.item_id") as myquery INTO @sql
    -> FROM custom_fields;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| item_id | item_type | item_name  | item_description                   | size   | color  | size   | color  | memory | hard drive |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|       1 | clothing  | T-Shirt    | Get your t-shirt here              | large  | purple | large  | purple | NULL   | NULL       |
|       2 | clothing  | Polo Shirt | Another kind of short-sleeve shirt | medium | green  | medium | green  | NULL   | NULL       |
|       3 | computer  | macbook    | 2016 Macbook Pro with retina       | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | 16GB   | 512GB SSD  |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  I'm working on tracking how it works / what it does.

Comment: @cale_b - you can also execute the second statement direct as prepared statement. i will add a sample at the end of my answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

With mysql 5.7 you may consider retrieving attributes as a json:

```
SELECT 
    i.item_id,
    i.item_name,
    i.item_description,
    CONCAT('{',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(JSON_QUOTE(a1.attribute),
                        ':',
                        JSON_QUOTE(a1.value))
                SEPARATOR ','),
            '}') AS att
FROM
    item AS i
        INNER JOIN
    custom_fields AS a1 ON i.item_id = a1.item_id
        INNER JOIN
    custom_fields AS a2 ON i.item_id = a2.item_id
        AND a2.attribute = 'size'

WHERE
    a1.attribute IN ('color' , 'size')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY a2.value DESC
```

Results:

```
+---------+------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| item_id | item_name  | item_description                   | att                               |
+---------+------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|       2 | Polo Shirt | Another kind of short-sleeve shirt | {"size":"medium","color":"green"} |
|       1 | T-Shirt    | Get your t-shirt here              | {"size":"large","color":"purple"} |
+---------+------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Assuming custom_fields has a unique index (item_id, attribute).

`AND a2.attribute = 'size'` is dynamic part where you define the attribute to order by, as well as `a1.attribute IN ('color' , 'size')` where you define attributes to fetch.

It behaves slightly different from the original multi-join query. If one or more attributes are missing, it still return the item.

Comment: Interesting idea.  How would I sort by say "color" using this approach?

Comment: Just updated the answer with a bit of explanation. To sort by colour you will need to use `AND a2.attribute = 'color'`

Comment: I just realized as a distributed package, I can't reliably depend on mysql 5.7+ being installed.  Bummer, because this is a cool idea.

Comment: Well, for mysql <5.7 `JSON_QUOTE` might be replaced with `CONCAT-REPLACE` pair, so instead of `JSON_QUOTE(a1.attribute)` you end up with `CONCAT('"',REPLACE(a1.attribute,'"','\\"'),'"')`, but I'm not quite sure if it covers all edge cases and **always** results with valid JSON string.